# Detecting periodic patterns in data - how often are the meetings held?

Tags: data-analysis

Suppose some people I know frequently have meetings, and suppose I want to find out whether there's a pattern to when these meetings take place, and if so how often they occur.

I can take note of the days when they have meetings. If I assume that the first meeting took place on Day 0, then I might end up with a list of days like

$$[0, 14, 27, 41, 55, 70, 84, 91, 105, 112, 126],$$

meaning they also met up on Day 14, Day 27, etc. If I look at the gaps between the numbers, then I get

$$[14, 13, 14, 14, 15, 14, 7, 14, 7, 14],$$

which indicates to me that they probably have meetings every one or two weeks, most likely two.

If we suppose the list of days looked like this instead:

$$[0, 100, 162, 257, 339, 416, 434, 440, 443, 538, 549],$$

with gaps

$$[100, 62, 95, 82, 77, 18, 6, 3, 95, 11],$$

then I don't see much of a pattern there, and I'd assume that they meet up at random.

So my question is this: **Is there a good way of detecting whether there's a pattern to the days, and if so find out what the most likely frequency is?** (e.g. 14 days for the first example)

---

I tried guessing the frequency then checking how well it fits by sum of squared differences, but this turned out to be sensitive to outliers. This is a problem because we might have gaps like this:

$$[7, 7, 7, 6, 84, 7, 7, 6, 7],$$

which indicates to me that the meetings take place every week, but they also took a three month break in between.

Comment: They call these meetings anonymous for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You might try looking for peaks in the discrete Fourier transform of $X$ where $X(i) = 1$ if there is a meeting on day i$, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I just tried DFT and it gave some [pretty nice results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tZe5W.png) (the biggest peak there is 7 not 14 but I'm okay with that). It seems to work pretty well when there is a pattern, but is there a way of telling apart cases where the peaks are significant from when they're due to random input, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ojt9f.png)?